# The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Tags: java, list, arraylist, integer

Why doesn't this work?

```
private List<Integer> xShot = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     ...codes
     ...codes
     ...codes
     ...codes
     xShot.get(0) += 5;
```

Can't understand why the left-hand side of an assignment´isn't is a variable..

Someone help?

Comment: You're taking first element from list, then summing it with 5 and place result into nothing (actually to this particular integer) - that's the problem.
It's like you've wrote `5 += 5`.
5 from the left side is not a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to increment by 5 and aren't limited to `List<Integer>` specifically, you could avoid arguably verbose `xShot.set(0, xShot.get(0) + 5)` and do this instead:

```
List<AtomicInteger> xShot = new ArrayList<AtomicInteger>();
xShot.get(0).addAndGet(5);
```

This will increment the value of the [`AtomicInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) in `xShot.get(0)` by 5 in-place without further ado.

Answer (score 5):

`xShot.get(0)` is a method call that returns a value. A variable is something you declare with a type that holds a value, like `int x;`, `String name;`, or `List<Integer> xShot` from your example. Those are the only things in Java that you can assign a value to using an [assignment operator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 5):

Although xShot.get(0) is a number, it is not a variable. You need to provide a variable for this to work. That said

```
int i = xShot.get(0);
i += 5;
```

Will not work. `i` will be incremented by 5, but xShot's object in location 5 is not the same object. You need to get, modify, and set the variable.

For example:

```
xShot.set(0, xShot.get(0) + 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

`xShot.get(0)` *returns* an object; it isn't a *variable*, so you can't assign to it.

Also, `Integer` is immutable (you can't change its value), so you would have to *replace* the object at position `0` with a *new* `Integer` that has the calculated value.

You can achieve the intention of that line like this:

```
xShot.set(0, xShot.get(0) + 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is like saying in Java:

```
5 = 6; // "Assign 5 to 6"
```

The left side (`5`) isn't variable.

Why is this example statement relevant? Because of Java uses **always** "pass by value". Which means that the return *value* of a method is also "return by value".
This is pure mathematical: you can't change a value, you can change a variable. The same for Java. Five can never become six.
In other words: **Only a value can be assigned to a variable.**

So, the correct way of doing what you want is:

```
xShot.set(0, xShot.get(0) + 5);
```

**Edit:** In your situation: `xShot.get(int)` doesn't return a variable, but a value.

Answer (score 0):

The left-hand side of the assignment has to be explicitly a variable because in your case of statement , the expression could be a constant also , which would be a error if allowed